Extracting data from database using provided id with Laravel API and Postman
I attempted to follow the advice from my previous post, but it was unsuccessful. I'm developing an HTTP API request for an online bookstore. The database table I'm working with has 'bookId', 'userId', and 'Comment' columns. I aim to create a function in my controller class that returns a list of comments for a specific book, given its 'bookId'.
My migration, route, controller, and model classes, provided below, should be used for this function/request unless a new one is needed. I'm also unsure how to correctly test this in Postman, specifically how to provide the 'bookId' to verify if my function works.
I'm relatively new to Laravel and Postman, so any advice would be greatly appreciated. I've been unable to find relevant online documentation to assist me with this issue.
Controller-- The function being used is 'ShowComments'
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\CreateComment;
use App\Models\BookRating;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class BookRatingController extends Controller
{
    public function CreateRating( Request $request)
    {
       // create a function that inserts data to data base ( create a book rating)
       $bookrating = new BookRating; 
       $bookrating->Rating=$request->Rating;
       $bookrating->userId=$request->userId;
       $bookrating->bookId=$request->bookId;
       $bookrating->save();
       return ["Book Rating saved ! "];
       }

       public function CreateComment( Request $request)
       {
          // create a function that inserts data to data base ( create a book rating)
          $bookcomment = new CreateComment; 
          $bookcomment->Comment=$request->Comment;
          $bookcomment->userId=$request->userId;
          $bookcomment->bookId=$request->bookId;
          $bookcomment->save();
          return ["Comment saved ! "];
          }

    public function ShowComments(string $bookId)
    {
       // This will be the function used to return list of comments given a bookId. 

    }   
}

Model
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CreateComment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable =
    [
        'Comment',
        'userId',
        'bookId'
    ];
}

Migration
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('create_comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('Comment');
            $table->string('userId');
            $table->string('bookId');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('create_comments');
    }
};


Route
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\BookRatingController;
use App\Http\Models\BookRating;
use App\Http\Models\CreateComment;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "api" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('CreateRating',[BookRatingController::class, 'CreateRating']);//adding a bookrating to database API -- POST METHOD-- 
Route::post('CreateComment',[BookRatingController::class, 'CreateComment']);

Route::get('ShowComments', [CommentController::class, 'ShowComments']);


